# Python 3 re module. "cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object". Mac changer

Tags: python-3.x

I've built a program to change my Mac address.The following part works just fine:

```
import subprocess
import optparse
import re

def get_arguments():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="interface que terá seu Mac alterado")
    parser.add_option("-n","--mac", dest = "new_mac", help="New Mac address")
    (options, arguments) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.interface:
        parser.error("[-] Please specify an interface. Use --help for more info")
    elif not options.new_mac:
        parser.error("[-] Please specify a Mac. Use --help for mmore info")
    return options


def change_mac(interface, new_mac):
    print("[+] Changing Mac address for " + interface + " to " + new_mac)

    subprocess.call("sudo ip link set dev " + interface + " down", shell=True)
    subprocess.call("sudo ip link set dev " + interface + " address " + new_mac, shell=True)
    subprocess.call("sudo ip link set dev " + interface + " up", shell=True)
    print("***************************************************")

options = get_arguments()
change_mac(options.interface, options.new_mac)
```

**The problem is here:**

```
ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", options.interface])
mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
print(mac_address_search_result.group(0))
```

**I'm receiving the following error when I try to run the program:**

[+] Changing Mac address for enp5s0 to 00:1B:44:11:3A:B7

---

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "mac_changer.py", line 31,
>   in 
>       mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 182, in search
>       return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string) TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

I know I don't need the re module, still I would like to use it.

Comment: Sounds like you have to convert you result from bytes to a string, maybe ifconfig_result.decode("utf8").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, `ifconfig_result` is of type `bytes`, but `re.search` (and the other `re` functions) expect `str`.

You can fix this by simply converting `ifconfig_result` to `str` with [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode):

```
ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", options.interface]).decode()
```